# ipad rotation in iphone project

Tags: objective-c, ios, rotation, orientation

I've created a project that is targeted just for iPhone (for now) and I chose supported orientation only Portrait. On iPhone it works great, but when I launch my project on iPad my application is rotating! Actually I tried to make it a universal app and in iPad deployment info I chose supported orientation only Portrait, my app still rotated on iPad. How may I fix that?

Answer (score 4):

To only support Portrait mode in your view, implement the following in each of your views:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Also, you need to make sure that have set the **Supported Device Orientations** for each device as well:

[image]

[image]

Comment: But when I set supported orientation in project deployment info, shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: Should be. Maybe you have `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` already set, just make sure if you have this method that it matches mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually set the rotation values in the view controllers by implementing this function:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```